# Data Source Name overrides Data Source Definition

Tags: odbc, salesforce, ms-office, dsn

My Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus subscription updated over the weekend to Version 1708 (Build 8431.2153) and all of my MS Access external links to Salesforce data broke.

I am using the Progress DataDirect 7.1 drivers and I had created a USER DSN named "Salesforce".  It seems that the updated Microsoft software saw that name and immediately assumed that I was using Simba drivers even though the definition explicitly states that I am using the DataDirect drivers.

Renaming the data source fixed the problem.

I was also able to reproduce the problem in both Access and Excel by changing the name of a MySQL Data Source to "Salesforce".

So, in short, if you name your data source "Salesforce", then Microsoft will ignore the data source definition and assume you are using the Simba drivers

Comment: What's your question?